# How to display data coming from API in React buttons

Tags: reactjs, api, button, react-component

I am trying to display the array of data coming from each API call. Let's say I have a /fruits API and /pizza API. I want to display in a table format that's separated by each element in the json array. How would I do this in react, given the API code is working as expected:

```
function getFood() {
    const fruitResult = API.get("fruits", "/fruits", params, {
    });
    const pizzaResult = API.get('pizza", "/pizza", params, {

  });
}
```

The json let's say is:

```
data: {
  "food": [
    "fruits": [{
       "name":"apple",
       "price":"2.5",
       "weight":"1"
     },
      ...
     ] 
  ]

}
```

Ideally, I would want the price/weight to be clickable buttons and it would look something like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you at least show code of your component?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not showing how your component looks like.. I'll make you a functional component from scratch.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
function CustomComponent() {
  const [fruits, setFruits] = useState([]);
  const [pizza, setPizzas] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    function getOdds() {
      const fruitResult = API.get("fruits", "/fruits", params, {
      });
      const pizzaResult = API.get("pizza", "/pizza", params, {
      });
      return Promise.all([fruitResult, pizzaResult])
    }
    getOdds().then(([fruitsRes, pizzasRes]) => {
      setFruits(fruitsRes);
      setPizzas(pizzasRes);
    });
  }
  return (
    <div>
      {fruits.map(fruit => <button>{fruit}</button>)}
    </div>
  )
}
```